# Codeigniter array format

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

When a creating an array and get value of an certain column from the database, I have a array format whether is this the same or not?

`$result['user_name']`  and `$result[0]->user_name`

Comment: provide more detail, some code or data structure etc. normally in codeigniter we uses " $query->result_array() "  to fetch results as Associated array

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it's just 'regular' PHP. As @RashFlash pointed out, many times in Codeigniter, an array or object is created from the database result. The documentation for that is here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

So your first `$result['user_name']` is just referencing an array where the key is `'user_name'` and the latter is referencing a property of the first object in the array.

Often the processing/display of database results goes something like this object based example (taken from the above documentation).

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
        echo $row->title;
        echo $row->name;
        echo $row->body;
}
```

or

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['body'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> When a creating an array and get value of an certain column from the
>   database, i have a array format whether is this the same or not?
>
> ```
> $result['user_name'] and $result[0]->user_name
> ```

**In codeigniter**

```
$query->result() ;  // returns object

$query->result_array(); // returns array

$query->row();  // returns object

$query->row_array(); // returns array
```

**In PHP (very basic)**

To access array elements you have to use either `[]` or which you don't see that much, but which you can also use is `{}`.

```
echo $array[0];
echo $array{0};
```

To access an object property you have to use `->`.

```
echo $object->property;
```

If you have an object in another object you just have to use multiple `->` to get to your object property.

```
echo $objectA->objectB->property;
```

**Accessing Array:**

```
$ php -r '$a=array("s"=>123); echo $a{"s"}.PHP_EOL; echo $a["s"].PHP_EOL;'
123
123
```

**Accessing Object:**

```
php -r '$a=$b=new stdClass; $a->s="test"; $b->t="second"; $a->r=$b; echo $a->s.PHP_EOL; echo $a->r->t.PHP_EOL;'
test
second
```